# xss attack issue-- with servletoutputstream.write(b, 0, b.length);

Tags: java, xss, servlet-filters

```
byte b[] = do.getFileUploaded();
servletoutputstream = response.getOutputStream();
            servletoutputstream.write(b, 0, b.length);
```

i have an issue of XSS attack in the servletoutputstream.write(b, 0, b.length); syntax saying "Injection of data received from servlet request ("b") to servlet response (possible XSS attack)" how to fix it. i am using ESAPI for escaping and filtering the other xss attack issue. does anyone have any/alternative solution for this one
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the received data back to the sender. That's the reason for the message (what from?). The question is, why are you doing that? The solution is not to do it.

Comment: It may not make sense functionally, but is it technically invalid to do so?

Comment: Your tool is telling you that it provides a way for XSS attacks. I'd call that invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Response Header metadata  to binary.